# How to add custom validator to reactive forms in Angular5

Tags: angular5, custom-validators

I have the following `passwordvalidator` which I don't know how to attach into the html. The way I am invoking it now it's not working **`loginForm.controls.password.errors.passwordValidator`** 
See below in the actual code.

```
import { FormControl } from "@angular/forms";

    export class PasswordValidator {

        static getPasswordValidator() {
            return function passwordValidator(control: FormControl): { [s: string]: boolean } {

                // Write code here..
                if (!control.value.match(/^((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{6,})/)) {
                    return { invalidPassword: true };
                }

                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then this is how I am using it in **login.ts**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
      username: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      password: ['',
        Validators.compose([
          Validators.required,
          PasswordValidator.getPasswordValidator()
        ]
        )]
    });
  }
```

But can't find out how to add it to the formcontrol in **login.html**

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input id="password" formControlName="password" matInput placeholder="Password">
  </mat-form-field>
  <br>
  <div *ngIf="loginForm.controls.password.invalid && (loginForm.controls.password.dirty || loginForm.controls.password.touched)"
    class="alert alert-danger">
    <div class="error mat-body-2" *ngIf="loginForm.controls.password.errors.required">
      You must fill out your password
    </div>
    <div class="error mat-body-2" *ngIf="loginForm.controls.password.errors.passwordValidator && !loginForm.controls.password.errors.required">
      Invalid email password
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if the key `invalidPassword` exist in errors of that controls or not like that

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input id="password" formControlName="password" matInput placeholder="Password">
</mat-form-field>
<br>
<div *ngIf="loginForm.controls.password.invalid && (loginForm.controls.password.dirty || loginForm.controls.password.touched)"
    class="alert alert-danger">
    <div class="error mat-body-2" *ngIf="loginForm.controls.password.errors.required">
    You must fill out your password
    </div>
    <div class="error mat-body-2" *ngIf="loginForm.controls.password.errors.invalidPassword && !loginForm.controls.password.errors.required">
    Invalid email password
    </div>
```